# How to correctly handle a list made of generic classes with methods that also have generic returns

Tags: c#, json, generics, interface, abstract-class

I believe this question is answered simply, but since I've been banging my head on this issue for a while, I've might have trouble seeing the overall picture.

I want to load multiple files (in this case, JSON), so I created a `DataLoader` class that will handle this. In this class, I'm creating a list of `ILoaders` that the class will iterate and load, so that in the future if I use something else than the JSON, the abstraction will already be implemented.

```
public class DataLoader{

    private List<IDataLoaded> allDataLoaded = new List<IDataLoaded>();

    private List<ILoader> loaderLists = new List<ILoader> (){
        new JSONLoader<RootSpacecrafts>(),
        new JSONLoader<RootWeapons>()
    };

    public void LoadData(){
        foreach(ILoader loader in loaderLists){
            loader.Read ();
            IDataLoaded dataLoaded = loader.Load ();
            allDataLoaded.Add(dataLoaded);
        }
    }
}
```

When I created my `JSONLoader` class and made it implement the `ILoader` interface, I noticed that I had to transform `ILoader` into a generic interface: I will always need to provide the root class `T` that the `JSONLoader` will put the data into, and also needed it to be flexible and return a `List<T>` containing the data loaded.

So now my `JSONLoader` class reads as:

```
public class JSONLoader<T> : ILoader<T> where T : IDataLoaded, new(){

    private string fileContents;
    private T output = new T();
    private List<T> outputlist;

    public void Read(){
        fileContents = File.ReadAllText(Paths.Get(output.Descriptor));
        outputlist =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(fileContents);
    }

    public List<T> Load(){
        return outputlist;
    }   
}
```

And the ILoader:

```
public interface ILoader<T>{
    void Read();
    List<T> Load();
}
```

Now when I went back to the `DataLoader` class, as you can see, I lost the flexibility to call the `ILoader`, because I will need to tell what is the generic class being used.

I tried to encapsulate it in another interface, but then the `loader.Load()` call in the `DataLoader` was broken, since it returns a `List<T>`.

Right now I'm feeling that to fix in one side, I will break the other. I've been trying to think a good combination of abstract classes and interfaces to isolate everything accordingly, but I'm having a big trouble in visualizing how it would all fit (I'm fairly new to C# and don't yet have the mental agility in it to see what I should do and encapsulate).

I'm using this as an exercise to learn C# and was hoping to use the best programming practices possible. I'd like to have a robust code, without duplication and with the minimum amount of dependencies between classes. I was also hoping in getting an explanation and not simply a working code. Thank you!

Comment: What usages of `T` do you have inside `ILoader`? Only for loading the values?

Comment: Also, I'm assuming `RootSpacecrafts` and `RootWeapons` implement `IDataLoaded`?

Comment: `T` is used for deserializing the json into the correct root class and for returning the corresponding `List<T>` of deserialized data.

Comment: Yes, they implement `IDataLoaded`. Currently that is just for getting the path of the JSON file that is a property of the root class.

Comment: Then I don't see the problem. Iterating `foreach(ILoader<IDataLoadeD> loader in loaderLists)` should give you the flexibility you want, shouldn't it?

Comment: I believe you are absolutely right. I can't confirm it now because I have some issues with the interfaces (it complains that it cannot convert `JSONLoader<RootSpacecrafts>` expression to type `ILoader<IDataLoaded>`), but hopefully everything is fine afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have some issues with the interfaces (it complains that it cannot
>   convert JSONLoader expression to type
>   ILoader)

That is because `List<T>` isn't covariant. If you want this to work, instead of  exposing `List<T>`, you can expose an `IEnumerable<T>` which is covariant in `T`, and also make your `Loader<T>` be covariant with `Loader<out T>`:

```
public class DataLoader
{
    private IEnumerable<IDataLoaded> allDataLoaded = new List<IDataLoaded>();
    private IEnumerable<ILoader<IDataLoaded>> loaderLists = new
                                                            List<ILoader<IDataLoaded>>
    {
        new JsonLoader<RootSpacecrafts>(),
        new JsonLoader<RootWeapons>()
    };

    public void LoadData()
    {
        foreach (ILoader<IDataLoaded> loader in loaderLists)
        {
            loader.Read();
            allDataLoaded = loader.Load();
        }
    }
}

public interface ILoader<out T>
{
    void Read();
    IEnumerable<T> Load();
}

public class JsonLoader<T> : ILoader<T> where T : IDataLoaded, new()
{
    private string fileContents;
    private T output = new T();
    private IEnumerable<T> outputlist;

    public void Read()
    {
        fileContents = File.ReadAllText("");
        outputlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(fileContents);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Load()
    {
        return outputlist;
    }
}
```

Comment: `The covariant type parameter 'T' must be invariantly valid on 'ILoader<T>.Load()'` From what I understand, this happens when using both co- and contra-variance in the interface. But the ILoader seems to be covariant and not contra-variant. Do you have an idea what could be the conflict here?

Comment: If `T` is covariant, it can't be passed as an input parameter to a method inside `ILoader`.

Comment: Though it isn't passed as an input, is the `private T output = new T();` in the `JSONLoader<T>` implementation of the `ILoader<T>` enough to break the covariance?

Comment: No, that shouldn't be a problem. Though i'd wonder why you need that at all.

Comment: I need to instantiate it in order to get the property that has the file path. It looks ugly, but I'm hoping to organize it better once I get things working. Thanks for the help, once again!

Comment: Just an update: since I'm currently using Unity, it seems that IEnumerable<T> is not covariant: `public interface IEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable`, hence the error. Nonetheless, this was great exercise to get to know the usefulness of the covariancy!

Comment: @Miguel Really? That's weird. Doesn't unity use the regular BCL?

Comment: According to what I investigated, it uses a custom build of Mono. I also think it's weird, since co/contravariance seems to be implemented, just not into the generic IEnumerable.